# Where to put Next.js cookie validation API call?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies

I have SSG Next.js website (domain.com) with Nodejs BE. React application (subdomain.domain.com) where cookies are generated for login and where access_token is stored. What I wanna do is to get access-cookie from the website, check if it's valid and if so change header and some CTA buttons within the website.

My question is: "What is the best place to make API call and why?"

The requirements are that it should stay as SEO friendly as possible.

At first I tried to put it into middleware, but I think that it will add some time to each request and I'm not sure if it runs on each page open because of SSG.